# Odoo can't find PyPDF2 attribute

Tags: python, linux, odoo, pypdf

## Specs

I Use `Kali Linux` and `Odoo 15`  and `python 3.9`

and this is the config file :

```
[options]
 addons_path = /home/ammar/Downloads/15.0/odoo/addons
 admin_passwd = admin123
 db_host = localhost
 db_maxconn = 64
 db_port = 5432
 db_user = odoo15
 http_port = 8015
```

also, I am new to using Odoo so don't judge me.

## Error

There Is an error that I keep Facing which is:

```
Traceback (most reacent call last):
  File "/home/ammar/Downloads/15.0/odoo/odoo-bin" line 5, in <module> import odoo

File "home/ammar/Downloads/15.0/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
  PyPDF2.filters.decompress = _decompress

AttributeError: module 'PyPDF2' has no attribute 'filters'
```

I tried to remove the line 84 and more errors came out and I also tried reinstalling the PyPDF2 module to version 1.26.0 and it didn't work and I tried installing pillow and still the same error

I tried to install `pypdf` version 1.26.0 and It didn't work also tried to install `pillow` and it still didn't **work**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have all the needed versions of the python packages you need to run Odoo by installing the requirements.txt from https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/requirements.txt using pip like:

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: tried it but still got the same error but thanks for you help

Comment: Make sure you install it on the same Python enviroment you are using to run your Odoo installation. I mean if you use base system Python 3.9 you need to install it using pip3.9 of the base system python installation. Or if you are using a virtualenv you need to install the requirements with the virtualenv activated or with the pip of the virtualenv